# rdbms & big data into a datamart?

Tags: hadoop, analytics, bigdata, rdbms, datamart

I have an RDBMS (SQL Server/ Oracle) and a Hadoop database on the other end.
Primary-key 'customer' is common in both data stores.

A few questions:

1. Is it possible to have a datamart that can pull data from both RDBMS
   & Big data and produce reports? What would be a tool example?
2. Does the datamart itself need to be a RDBMS store or can it be some in-memory stuff?
3. Whats the best way to run data analytics in this environment?
4. What about data visualization?

Or should I just get all data into an RDBMS data warehouse and then solve for these questions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data virtualization or data federation is what you're looking for - i.e. the ability to access a single source that will access multiple resources as needed.

Databases usually have some limited capability in this area which lets you define external tables see for example [this link for Oracle and HDFS](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E27101_01/doc.10/e27365/directhdfs.htm)